# IP routing between two sites and allowing external access to both via Wireguard

Tags: routing, proxmox, wireguard

I have two Proxmox notes, in two separate locations. They are connected via a Wireguard Tunnel between the two sites (A and B). This tunnels all traffic destined for the other site through the tunnel on both.

- All servers on Node A use the range 10.0.0.0/24.
- All servers on Node B use the range 10.10.0.0/24

Any traffic from A destined for B, say for example, 10.10.0.100, would go via the Wireguard tunnel (wgAMS) to B. The reverse is the same from Node B (over wgLON).

However: I also have another Wireguard interface running on Node A (wg0 interface). I use this to allow remote access from mobile devices, laptops etc.

Clients connected to Node A over this wg0 interface (10.7.0.0/24) can access everything on Node A with no problems, however cannot reach anything in Node B. I've tried serveral different things but still can't get these to route correctly.

The output of `ip route` from Node A is below.

```
default via <WAN_IP> dev vmbr0 proto kernel onlink
10.0.0.0/24 dev vmbr2 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.1
10.7.0.0/24 dev wg0 proto kernel scope link src 10.7.0.1
10.10.0.0/24 dev wgAMS scope link
10.10.9.0/31 dev wgAMS proto kernel scope link src 10.10.9.0
```

Looking at this, it appears to me that these clients *should* be able to access 10.10.0.0/24 (Node B) - but they can't. Running tcpdump on the wg0 interface I can see sample ICMP/ping traffic but no responses.

I've tried adding PostUp rules to route the traffic on the wg0 interface config via wgAMS for Node B IPs but this didn't help either.

I largely followed [this guide](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/wireguard-vpn-site2site) for the site-to-site tunnel, for reference.

Comment: missing in the question: The output of ip route from Node B, and actually the whole setup on both sides.